# Why arsin function has range $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

While studying in P.75 of [inverse trigonometric functions](http://1drv.ms/1ROShSB) it tells we have to restrict our domain before finding the inverse.But I can't get why we choose $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$?Why can't we choose $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ where the function arcsin is invertible on this interval?

Answer (score 0):

You totally can. You can choose any interval where it's invertable. It's just "natural" to choose $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ as most "real" angles are around there.

Comment: :Could you tell what did you meant by 'real' angles?

Comment: @justin Would a carpenter tell you 45 degrees or 765 degrees?

Comment: :That's true.Why do we include negative values in the range when we actually can start from 90 to 270 degrees where it's all positive?

Comment: @justin You could, but I think having 0 is nice.That's really all there is to it.

Comment: :Yeah they(DKW) might have selected the first half of the sin function.